# Load-testing a thick client Windows Forms application

Tags: c#, winforms, performance, servicestack, load-testing

We've got a thick-client Windows Forms application that uses ServiceStack to connect to the application server (which, naturally, is also implemented using ServiceStack). I'd like to configure some load tests for this server, but I'm not sure how to proceed.

There is a bunch of load-testing software out there, but it looks like all of it relies on the "hey, please record my Web browsing session and then play it back" approach. This won't work in our case, since we don't use a Web browser. To make matters worse, some of our requests are not exactly REST-based; instead, they are complex objects that contain multiple relevant fields (e.g. some advanced search options, lists of ranges that need to be loaded, etc.). This makes configuring requests a little more difficult than just typing "myserver/api/get_stuff/1234".

So, is there some ready-made load-testing framework designed specifically for ServiceStack ? Barring that, is there some generic framework that will allow me to create custom requests by hand reasonably easily ? Or should I just bite the bullet and roll my own ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can checkout the [HTTP Benchmarks](https://github.com/ServiceStack/HttpBenchmarks) application, whilst it's built with ServiceStack, it's not for ServiceStack, but can handle hand-crafted urls.

There is also a portable version that can be run locally at:
https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Gap#download

It includes a Windows build of `ab.exe` (the [Apache Benchmark Utility](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/programs/ab.html)) which does the actual benchmarking and outputs its results into text files which can be visualized and exported with **Http Benchmarks**. Here are some examples of existing benchmarks:

- [Performance of different RDBMS within an ASP.NET Web Application](https://httpbenchmarks.servicestack.net/databases-in-asp-net)
- [Performance of different ServiceStack Hosts](https://httpbenchmarks.servicestack.net/servicestack-hosts)

It includes a [README.txt](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Gap/tree/master/src/BenchmarksAnalyzer/build) that includes instructions on how to use `ab.exe`. There are a number `*.bat` scripts showing how you can run multiple benchmarks in 1 `.bat script` on the [HttpBenchmarks](https://github.com/ServiceStack/HttpBenchmarks) project homepage, e.g [run-selfhost-benchmarks.bat](https://github.com/ServiceStack/HttpBenchmarks/blob/master/run-selfhost-benchmarks.bat)

Using a utility like `ab.exe` is nice as it's simple and highly configurable and as it's command-line utility, can easily be automated should you wish to automate and integrate it into a CI Server.

Comment: Thanks mythz, I'm going to chek out the application right now, but before I do: am I allowed to use it if I'm working on a commercial product ?

Comment: @Bugmaster yeah the source code itself is open source and the portable version fits in ServiceStack's free quotas so no commercial license is needed.

Comment: thanks, that's pretty cool. Unfortunately, I can't quite get ab.exe to work with my server. No matter what I do, it times out; meanwhile, wget of the same URL works fine. Weirdly, ab.exe does seem to work with external URLs, so is there something blindingly obvious that I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: @Bugmaster not sure it should just work, does it work for any urls? i.e. internal?

Comment: It looks like the tests immediately fail as soon as I try more than one simultaneous request. Is this some sort of a limitation in ServiceStack ? Other URLs work fine, internal and external...

Comment: @Bugmaster There's no such limitation within ServiceStack, these are [actual results from different ServiceStack hosts](https://httpbenchmarks.servicestack.net/servicestack-hosts). The entire [HttpBenchmarks](https://github.com/ServiceStack/HttpBenchmarks) repository is setup for benchmarking different [ServiceStack Hosts](https://github.com/ServiceStack/HttpBenchmarks/tree/master/servers).

Comment: Ok, sorry about that, the error was caused by MiniProfiler, somehow. I turned it off, and now it works perfectly, with one exception: it looks like BenchmarkAnalyzer is using an int32 to represent the total size downloaded. In my case, the test downloaded 5GB, so BenchmarkAnalyzer crashed with an OverflowExeption.

Comment: @Bugmaster ok cool, changed to use longs in [this commit](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Gap/commit/66d9fc19616f924f2bbae7c8ef8ddb14ae6b612b), the downloads should now have the update.

Answer (score 0):

NOTE: This answer is around a generic test framework, not specifically ServiceStack.

The Test/Professional/Ultimate versions of Visual Studio include a load and performance testing framework built around MSTest. If I remember correctly, the framework also supports NUnit and other test frameworks.

This framework also integrates nicely with TFS metrics, reporting and shows up on the build dashboard. Here's a quick-start tutorial: [Create and run a load test](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182594.aspx)

A lot of the documentation shows web tests, but you can just as easily use it for desktop apps.

In addition, if you are testing through the UI, take a look at the Microsoft UI Automation Framework, which gives you access to UI controls on your application. You can read more at [UI Automation Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747327.aspx).